# Adding a second filter to my custom filter seems to break Angular

Tags: angularjs, filter

I had created my first custom filter to display phone numbers the other day. I got the filter off of SO and was able to get it to work. Now I'm looking to add a second custom filter to do some searching on more than one parameter (a member's FirstName and LastName). I was given that filter from another member and it looks like it will work. However when I added that filter to my existing filters.js file it seems to have caused my Angular to not work. Anyone know if I'm adding this correctly or if I'm missing something?

Here is the original filter in a file named filters.js.

```
angular.module('appFilters', [])
    .filter('phone', function () {
        return function (phone) {
            if (!phone) { return ''; }

            var value = phone.toString().trim().replace(/^\+/, '');

            if (value.match(/[^0-9]/)) {
                return phone;
            }

            var country, city, number;

            switch (value.length) {
                case 10: // +1PPP####### -> C (PPP) ###-####
                    country = 1;
                    city = value.slice(0, 3);
                    number = value.slice(3);
                    break;

                case 11: // +CPPP####### -> CCC (PP) ###-####
                    country = value[0];
                    city = value.slice(1, 4);
                    number = value.slice(4);
                    break;

                case 12: // +CCCPP####### -> CCC (PP) ###-####
                    country = value.slice(0, 3);
                    city = value.slice(3, 5);
                    number = value.slice(5);
                    break;

                default:
                    return phone;
            }

            if (country == 1) {
                country = "";
            }

            number = number.slice(0, 3) + '-' + number.slice(3);

            return (country + " (" + city + ") " + number).trim();
        };
    });
```

Here I added the searching filter. I just came right before the last semi-colon and added the filter there. It looks like it would be the correct placement to me.

```
angular.module('appFilters', [])
    .filter('phone', function () {
        return function (phone) {
            if (!phone) { return ''; }

            var value = phone.toString().trim().replace(/^\+/, '');

            if (value.match(/[^0-9]/)) {
                return phone;
            }

            var country, city, number;

            switch (value.length) {
                case 10: // +1PPP####### -> C (PPP) ###-####
                    country = 1;
                    city = value.slice(0, 3);
                    number = value.slice(3);
                    break;

                case 11: // +CPPP####### -> CCC (PP) ###-####
                    country = value[0];
                    city = value.slice(1, 4);
                    number = value.slice(4);
                    break;

                case 12: // +CCCPP####### -> CCC (PP) ###-####
                    country = value.slice(0, 3);
                    city = value.slice(3, 5);
                    number = value.slice(5);
                    break;

                default:
                    return phone;
            }

            if (country == 1) {
                country = "";
            }

            number = number.slice(0, 3) + '-' + number.slice(3);

            return (country + " (" + city + ") " + number).trim();
        };
    })
    .filter('customMemberFilter', function () {
        return function (memberList, query) {
            // make sure a query value was passed
            if (query) {
                query = query.toLowerCase();
                var out = [];
                angular.forEach(memberList, function (member) {
                    if ((member.FirstName.toLowerCase().includes(query)) ||
                        (member.LastName.toLowerCase().includes(query))) {
                        out.push(member);
                    }
                });
                return out;
            } else {
                return memberList;
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is my app.js where I add the filter.js (called appFilters) to the module.

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module('troopApp', ['ngRoute','appFilters']);      //('moduleName', [array of injected modules])

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'MembersController',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/members.html'
            })
            .when('/memberDetail/:memberId', {
                controller: 'MemberDetailController',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/memberDetail.html'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});
    });

}());
```

Here is my HTML.

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Members</h2>
    <p />
    Filter Name: <input type="text" ng-model="memberFilter" />
    <p />
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
            <tr class="info">
                <th ng-click="doSort('FirstName')">First Name</th>
                <th ng-click="doSort('LastName')">Last Name</th>
                <th ng-click="doSort('EmailPrimary')">Email</th>
                <th ng-click="doSort('PhonePrimary')">Phone</th>
                <th>Is Scout</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="member in members | customMemberFilter:memberFilter  | orderBy:sortBy:reverse">
                <td>{{ member.FirstName }}</td>
                <td>{{ member.LastName }}</td>
                <td><a href="mailto:{{ member.EmailPrimary }}">{{ member.EmailPrimary }}</a></td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ member.PhonePrimary | phone }}</td>
                <td>{{ member.IsScout }}</td>
                <td clas="text-center"><a href="#/memberDetail/{{ member.MemberId }}">View</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks right and should be working. May we see how your controllers are defined? Are they in a separate .js file?

Comment: What's the error showing when your app breaks?!

Comment: @Lex...yes, the controllers are in separate files at the moment but that's something I'm going to look at consolidating if I can. Just taking baby steps to learn at the moment.

Comment: @Bettimms....I don't get any errors that I can see, it just shows me the Angular code as though it's not working. Example, it will show {{ FirstName }} on the page. It does that for all of my Angular mark up.

Comment: Well, I at least got past the supposed Angular not working. That was my fault. I'm working on a View called members.html which is part of the SPA and is injected into my Landing.html page. I was just clicking on Debug which took me directly to members.html which doesn't work. I have to go to landing.html first for it to work correctly. However, the search still doesn't work. I get the page to display my members but the search does nothing.

Comment: Anyone know if the way the custom filter is called in the <tr> tag is correct? Shouldn't I need to let Angular know that I am working with filtering by placing the "filter:" first? I tried "filter:customMemberFilter:memberFilter" but that didn't work either. My assumption here is that the first parameter lets Angular know I'm working with filtering, the second that I'll be using a function called customMemberFilter, and third being the ng-model it's tied to.

Comment: The first parameter is either `filter` or `yourCustomFilterName` - it lets Angular know if you are using the default filter or a custom one. You're going to have to sprinkle some console logging statements in your code to debug because this should all be working. Here is a simplied [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1gu92121/1/) showing that it works.

Comment: Thanks for the JSFiddle because seeing that made me find the issue. I'm not 100% sure I understand why yet but I was always concerned about the placement of the ending semi-colon in the filter.js file. I noticed on your project you didn't have that ending semi-colon. I removed mine and it worked. I'm guessing that because I'm injecting the 'appFilters' into the app.js file that the ending semi-colon probably stopped the rest of the JS code. However, when I just had one filter the ending semi-colon didn't seem to cause a problem so I'm not 100% sure why it needs to be removed.

Comment: I know this is extremely weird but I was showing a colleague and was trying to show him how the semi-colon seemed to be an issue but then of course it started working. I would think the ending semi-colon would need to be there in order to end the JS function. Maybe it was cached or something. Do you try to make it a habit of clearing the cache on occassion?

Comment: I always forget the last semi-colon when I'm using JSFiddle because I don't have Resharper or JSLint warning me about it. :) Javascript files will definitely get cached by the browser which would explain why adding a second filter wasn't working as expected. There are various strategies for overcoming the caching issue. It can be as simple as adding a querystring to your `src` attribute on your `<script></script>` tag.